# correlation matching audio files peak position

Tags: matlab, correlation

if i cross correlate an audio file with itself (which means there is no delay or difference), the peak position should be a zero or at the center of the cross correlation? [image]

that is really confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

cosinder [5,123,4] as a signal.
At n=-3, multiplying and accumulating [5,123,4,0,0,0] and [0,0,0,5,123,4] we get zero.

at n=0, we get 5*5+123*123+4*4

Again at n=3, we get zero.

So, the peak will be at zero displacement.
In the graph you have given, there could be a inherent shift in one of the signals, which will cause that offset. Can you check that?

Maybe, this would be better posted in dsp.SE ?

Comment: No its the same file with itself. here's the code: fft1=fft(s,wlen);         
fft2=fft(x,wlen);          
G12=fft1.*conj(fft2);     
G=G12/max(abs(G12),1e-6);  
g=real(ifft(G));          g=fftshift(g);

Comment: You are multiplying after the FFT? That would be convolution in time domain, right? I don't think the peak would be at the center if you are convolving a signal with itself - I mean its not guaranteed to be at any specific position, AFAIK.